# Bluez way to tell if connected device has BT Classic, BLE or both

Tags: systemd, bluetooth, d-bus, bluez

Is there a programmatic way to tell which transport layer (BD/BLE/Both) is used to connect to dev? I use sd_bus lib with C++ to handle DBus calls and signals.

Thanks!